# mysql - find match in comma seperated text field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autosuggest

I am having problems with output from my (MySQL) database.

attractionData database

```
 id |  tags
-------------------------------------

 1  |  castle a, castle b, fakecastle c
 2  |  museum a, fakemuseum b, museum c
 ...
```

And on a site I have an input field, which has autoSuggest function.
So in my jQuery I have an .keyup event, which send data to ajax file, and the ajax file outputs the list of suggestions (autosuggest).

So now if I type in the input "castle a..." it will output the "1" (im outputting the id).
And if i type in "museum a" it will return "2".

So my question is... Is it somehow possible that if I would type in "fakecastle" that it would return "1"? I know this could be done with the `explode(',', $string)`.

I've been messing around with FIND_IN_SET(), but I somehow didn't achieve the result I wanted.
So I am still stucked with

`mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM attractionData WHERE (tags LIKE '$search%') ")`
$search = text from the input field.

EDIT

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) == true && empty($_POST['search']) == false){
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM attractionData WHERE (tags LIKE '$search%') ")
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){
        echo "<li class='auto'>".$row['friendEmail'] ."</li>";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Ty, Sebastian

Comment: Normalize your table and all your problems will disappear. Stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: What is your "ajax" file? Do you cache the results?

Comment: check edit, I added ajax content

Comment: `tags LIKE '%$search%'` would do the trick, but this approach with tags is not good at all. You should have a separate table for tags with a may-to-many relationship with the current table (ie: a third table)

Answer (score 1):

Read about database normalisation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2NF) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3NF) and if you follow the steps of normalization, probably these issues will be sorted out automatically in the meantime AND your database will be more useful.